# Return Element name in linq to xml result

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I need to retrieve the element name at the same time I'm retrieving the element's attribute value and the element's value. I've managed to retrieve the element's attribute value and the element's value but cannot retrieve the element's name.

Here is the xml:

```
<appearance>
     <line-width type="stem">0.7487</line-width>
     <line-width type="beam">5</line-width>
     <line-width type="staff">0.7487</line-width>
     <line-width type="light barline">0.7487</line-width>
     <line-width type="heavy barline">5</line-width>
     <line-width type="leger">0.7487</line-width>
     <line-width type="ending">0.7487</line-width>
     <line-width type="wedge">0.7487</line-width>
     <line-width type="enclosure">0.7487</line-width>
     <line-width type="tuplet bracket">0.7487</line-width>
     <note-size type="grace">60</note-size>
     <note-size type="cue">60</note-size>
     <distance type="hyphen">120</distance>
     <distance type="beam">8</distance>
 </appearance>
```

and here is my linq query

```
  Dim categories = From category In ScoreXml.Descendants("appearance") _
    let El = category.Elements _
    from Att in El _
    let myAtt = att.attribute("type").value _
    let myEl = el.value _
    Select myAtt, myEl
```

I'm adding the result set to a list and need the element's name to differentiate between the identical attribute values. i.e, beam is an attribute value for both the elements line-width and distance. I need a result like "line-width" - "beam" - "5" and "distance" - "beam" - "8".

I've tried many things and can't even remember what I've done now. I'm starting to go around in circles. I know I've come close accessing the attribute's parent in a sub query then accessing the element name but I just tried to replicate what I did for an example but can't remember how I did it. Anyways, doing it with the sub query left me with a Cartesian product result that is obviously useless.

I hope my question and need as clear. How do I access/return each element's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`XElement.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) or `XElement.Name.LocalName` to get element name, for example :

```
Dim categories = From category In ScoreXml.Descendants("appearance") _
    let El = category.Elements _
    from Att in El _
    let myAtt = att.attribute("type").value _
    let myEl = el.value _
    Select myAtt, myEl, Att.Name.LocalName
```

Comment: Thanks. It's so simple. I think I've been staring at the screen for far to long. Thanks again.